# Visualize control points mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visualization

I want to show a curve with some control points where the user can adjust the curve by using control points, in my mfc application.
Could you please suggest me some good library?
I am using visual c++ 2008.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use GDI+ you can just use the [DrawCurve()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Thanks @Redeye. Does it allow the user to change the curve using control points?

Comment: It depends how you want to control the curve. DrawCurve() draws a cardinal spline between the points you pass to it, so they are what you control the curve. There's also a DrawBezier() function if you want more control than just drawing through the points, but it's a bit more complicated to get going.